# Certain Netbeans Libraries seem to be missing in Ubuntu so program don't work

Tags: java, netbeans

I tried to install the certain libraries for Netbeans to make an application.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

Which libraries do I need to install via apt-get

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.imgscalr.Scalr;
import org.imgscalr.Scalr.Method;
import org.imgscalr.Scalr.Mode;
import JMyron.*;
```

What netbeans is telling me that it doesn't exist. I think I am missing necessary libraries for Netbeans to get theses to work. Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post a picture. I think the netbeans that I installed is lacking the required libraries. Or I just got the wrong version of netbeans.

Comment: How did you try to install those libraries, and which version of netbeans are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of that can be installed directly by the package manager and the absence of libraries has nothing to do with Netbeans. The error messages are from the Java compiler.

Simply add the libraries to your Java project via project properties. AWT and Swing are part of the Java JDK/JRE.

Additionally libraries, normally JAR files, you need to download at the project pages and add into your Java project, eg. `org.imgscalr` and `JMyron`.

Comment: (Facepalm!)   ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Control the address of your installed JDK inside Netbeans. Maybe Netbeans does not know where JDK is.
At my first install of Netbeans 12.6 I had the same problem, it told me it could not find any package.
I solved by updating the compiler settings in Netbeans(I set the right path for JDK in my system) as I hadn't paid enough attention during the installation process.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1198922)